# how to differentiate the same user on different browser/tab/windows on meteor?

Tags: meteor

Imagine, I have a user that connects on a meteor app on 2 different browser tabs, or 2 different browsers, or 2 different computer.

My app needs to distinguish that with a unique id (userid+???).

What can I use to identify this on the client and on the server?

A use case is for example, a user locks a field to be able to edit it, we don't want anybody else to edit it even if it's the same user on another tab/windows/browser/computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
Meteor.startup(function () {
    window.uniqueUser = Meteor.uuid();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be interested in [`browser-store`](https://github.com/awwx/meteor-browser-store#readme) which will let you reactively share data across multiple open browsers and tabs.

Comment: Meteor already does this. He was looking for a way to differentiate the different tabs.