# In Meteor, how can i identify connection / a user of a site on the server, regardless of whether or not they're logged in?

Tags: javascript, meteor

How can i identify a specific connection on the server in Meteor. Similar to what you could accomplish with `Session` on the client - somewhere to put data related to the current connection.

Sort of like [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14588354/how-to-differentiate-the-same-user-on-different-browser-tab-windows-on-meteor), but on the server, not the client.

I can see that the Meteor Accounts package uses the following code in the `Meteor.userId` method:

```
var currentInvocation = Meteor._CurrentInvocation.get();
if (!currentInvocation)
  throw new Error("Meteor.userId can only be invoked in method calls. Use this.userId in publish functions.");
```

But when I try to use `Meteor._CurrentInvocation` in my code, it is `undefined`, rather than a `Meteor.EnvironmentVariable` object, as implied in the livedata package. And, as evidenced by the prefixing underscore, it's a private API, and should probably be avoided in general application code ;)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK - i was overcomplicating the issue, and coming at it from completely the wrong direction.

The context of any Meteor.method calls has a `connection` property [as described here](http://docs.meteor.com/#method_connection). This connection property is [described here](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_onconnection), and can be used to persist data across method calls for the duration of the connection.

It is accessible in publish functions and `Meteor.methods` methods.